# wordpress pages return 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a very strange problem.

The blog has a permalink structure `/%category%/%title%/`. Everything works fine for posts but when accessing pages by directly typing their URL, I get 404. I noticed this when checking the Google Webmasters Tools. The pages open fine when clicking on their link within the site.

The last thing I should mention is that the titles contain some non Latin characters but they are properly encoded.

Does WordPress check the `referrer` header and makes some decisions based on its value?

Look at the headers that Firefox sends when accessing the pade directly and it returns 404 and when clicking on internal link:

```
Host    localhost:8088
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
```

---

```
Host    localhost:8088
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
Referer http://localhost:8088/dani/
```

The only difference is the `referer` header. Very strange.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the case but something similar could happen if you don't choose a category for your post.. are you sure that you checked at least one of the categories (the one that you want to use in your url)?

Comment: It happens to pages, posts are working fine.

Comment: `Starting Permalinks with %category% is strongly not recommended for performance reasons.` thats what wordpress says, http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks for more information check under %category%

Comment: @Val: thanks for the tip. Do you know if WP checks in some way the referrer header?

Comment: try and use a force refresh, ctrl + r a few times or hold it down, could be a cache problem, also, I know they check for referrer, but don't know where abouts, because they use alot of redirects, especially when on login page. hope that helps

Comment: @Val: thanks again. It is not the refresh, though.

Comment: oh I think I know, google does not like redirecting pages, you should use a plugin, dunno what is called, yet but it does it throught `.htaccess` automatically, which is google friendly :), but if you search for "redirection" on wp plugins might come up :)

Comment: @Val: I noticed the problem in Google Webmasters Tools but it is not related to the goole bot. When I try to open a WP page directly by typing its URL, it happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4502/discussion-between-val-and-martin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be not in the referer header but in the casing of the utf-8 url parts. The internal links are bult with lower-case letters as:

```
http://localhost:8088/dani/%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3/
```

and the page titles have the same look. But when typing a URL in a browser, it encodes the string with upper-case letters as:

```
http://localhost:8088/dani/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3/
```

which doesn't match the title of the page.